# Run time issue in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have a run time issue in ballerina. I have saved all urls in a ballerina.conf file in the root directory.
so i call them like this in s service file which is at src/folder/service.bal file. for an example this is the code fragment i used

```
http:Client PeopleHrClient = new (config:getAsString("ROLE_SERVICE"));
```

In the config file the value for the NETSUITE_ROLE_SERVICE is like below

```
ROLE_SERVICE = "https://example/rest/roles"
```

after a successful build I ran the ballerina service at the target/bin directory.

```
ballerina run opdClaims.jar
```

but I met with the below error

[image: Error which occurred]

but when I run the ballerina service from the root directory it works fine

```
ballerina run target/bin/opdClaims.jar
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found two ways as answers to my question.

1. If I can copy and paste the ballerina.conf file into the target/bin
   directory and run the ballerina service, this issue will be solved.
2. And also as I got to know, we can pass the path of the config file
   as a parameter when we start running the service.

   ballerina run serviceFileName.bal --b7a.conf.file=pathToConfFile

Answer (score 1):

To provide a config file to your program, use the `--b7a.config.file=path/to/file` property when running your program.

e.g.,

```
$ ballerina run program.bal --b7a.config.file=path/to/file
```

In addition to the above, there's another method in which Ballerina automatically picks up the config file (i.e., without having to provide the above mentioned property). For this, you have to:

1. Have the config file named as `ballerina.conf`
2. Place the `ballerina.conf` file in the current directory (i.e., the directory from which you run your program)

Note that this is just a convenience mechanism for providing a config file.